# Disconnecting From Qt VNC Server causes Segmentation Fault on Server

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, qt5, vnc

I'm running my application with Qt 5.15.10 on Linux with VNC. I'm developing a Qt based VNC client but when disconnecting I encounter a segmentation fault on the server. This does not occur with existing vnc clients such as RealVNC and TightVNC.

Packet captures show I'm sending and receiving the FIN,ACK on the TCP socket and I'm also sending the final ACK same as the other two applications.

I've tried disconnecting using `QAbstractSocket::disconnectFromHost()` and just `QAbstractSocket::close()` with the same result.

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. Have managed to solve this?

Comment: @NoobNoob I can't remember if it was my application on my Linux device or my Qt VNC app, but I was mistakenly building with 5.12. I moved them both to 5.15 and the issue went away